# Multiple data sets and type for Rails link_to call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While the [documentation for link_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) is explicit about how to handle a single set of custom data attributes, the following URL has multiple data calls, including data subsets of the data attribute.  I suspect the attempts up to now have failed because of logical loops regarding the `data` option...

```
https://domain.me/chart?c={
  type:'bar',
  data:{
    labels:['01','02','03','04', '05'], 
    datasets:[
      {label:'A',data:[1,2,3,4,5]},
      {label:'B',data:[10,11,12,13,14]}
    ]
  }
}
```

How can the link_to rails call be composed to properly generate this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
"https://domain.me/chart?c=#{{
  type:'bar',
  data:{
    labels:['01','02','03','04', '05'], 
    datasets:[
      {label:'A',data:[1,2,3,4,5]},
      {label:'B',data:[10,11,12,13,14]}
    ]
  }
}.to_query}"
```

Which generates:

```
https://domain.me/chart?c=data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Blabel%5D=A&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=1&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=2&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=3&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=4&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=5&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Blabel%5D=B&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=10&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=11&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=12&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=13&data%5Bdatasets%5D%5B%5D%5Bdata%5D%5B%5D=14&data%5Blabels%5D%5B%5D=01&data%5Blabels%5D%5B%5D=02&data%5Blabels%5D%5B%5D=03&data%5Blabels%5D%5B%5D=04&data%5Blabels%5D%5B%5D=05&type=bar
```

You may need to fiddle with that a bit.